# Microsoft desktop 7000 lagging receiver

Tags: keyboard, mouse, hardware-failure, intellimouse

I am having problems with my receiver that is delivered with my Microsoft Desktop 7000. Occasionally, once a day, the mouse ánd keybard start lagging. Typing becomes undoable and the mouse switches all over the screen.

And then after 2 minutes, everything works just as usual. I have tried all different USB ports on my computer, even at the front. I also tried to get the mouse and keyboard closer while the problem was occurring, but it didn't help.

Could it be that the receiver is just broken once in a while? =S

The Microsoft Desktop 7000 consists of a Wireless Laser Mouse 7000 and a Wireless Laser Keyboard 7000.
My operating system is WIndows 7.

Comment: I'm assuming Windows, but you didn't say.  Please edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably either a driver or system service on your machine causing things to hang up, or more likely a radio interference problem.  The easiest test for that is to try moving the receiver much closer to the keyboard and mouse and see if it goes away.  (If it is interference, there's not much you can do short of moving anything that might be causing it.  Is there a microwave nearby? xD)

If it's NOT interference, and it's as sporadic as you say, you might have trouble pinning this down.  A good start would simply be noticing what's running (including scheduled system tasks in the background!) when this happens and then disabling things using that as a starting point.  (If it becomes more frequent, running something like LatencyMon or even XPerf might be more feasible, but it's not especially useful to have those going all day.)

Comment: I have already tried to move the keyboard and mouse closer to the receiver. But that didn't help. And the problem is that most of the time it works fine. Maybe I could test this by adding an extra wired mouse and see if it also gives hiccups?

Comment: @Marnix - That's worth a try, as long as it's the same frequency.  It's the difficulty of REPLICATING this that makes testing tough, though. :/  Hell, it's entirely possible there's just a very infrequent radio source nearby coming from the neighbors or something that's freaking it out!  ...do you live near a large military installation? ;)